# Solving this Euler's ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As part of a tangent of my course, I've to pick up how to solve Euler's DE on the go.

I have the equation $$\text{x $\phi $'' +$\phi $'+}\text{$\lambda $x}^{-1}\text{$\phi $=0}$$

Is this in the right form? I'm asking because the in form on an Euler's DE, the first non-constant coefficient term is an $$x^2$$ instead of $$x$$.

Comment: Yes, if you multiply both sides by $x$, you get the right form.

Comment: It was originally in 'that' form (the above equation multiplied by x as you've said. This is a sturm-Liouville problem.

I was wondering if it is possible for me to solve this equation as it is?

Comment: Yes, you should just solve it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODE is homogeneous. Search for particular solutions on the form $\phi=x^a$

$a(a-1)+a+\lambda=0$ leads to $a=\pm \sqrt{-\lambda}$ if $\lambda \neq 0$

$$\phi(x)=c_1 x^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}+c_2 x^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}$$

Or, on other forms :

$\phi(x)=c_1 \cosh(\sqrt{-\lambda}\ln|x|)+c_2 \sinh(\sqrt{-\lambda}\ln|x|)$ if $\lambda<0$

$\phi(x)=c_1 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\ln|x|)+c_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\ln|x|)$ if $\lambda>0$

$\phi(x)=\frac{c_1}{x}+c_2$ in particular case $\lambda=0$